# jQuery this inside event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I tought that I really understand use of `this` in jQuery/JS, but this showes me that I'm wrong. I wanted to add class on DOM element and I used this:

```
$("#content").on("click",function(){
    this.addClass("bonus");
});
```

But nothing happened, so I changed second line of code to and it worked:

```
 $("#content").addClass("bonus");
```

Shouldn't `this` in first example refer to `$("#content")` already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` refers to the DOM element that was triggered.  It's not a jQuery object, but a native DOM object.

You need to do:

```
$(this).addClass("bonus");
```

Answer (score 3):

`this` by itself is the native DOM element, you need `$(this)` which is a jQuery element with the method `addClass`